# Iterating over the lines of a file

Tags: scala, io, iterator

I'd like to write a simple function that iterates over the lines of a text file. I believe in `2.8` one could do:

```
def lines(filename: String) : Iterator[String] = { 
    scala.io.Source.fromFile(filename).getLines
}
```

and that was that, but in `2.9` the above doesn't work and instead I must do:

```
def lines(filename: String) : Iterator[String] = { 
    scala.io.Source.fromFile(new File(filename)).getLines()
}
```

Now, the trouble is, I want to compose the above iterators in a `for` comprehension:

```
for ( l1 <- lines("file1.txt"); l2 <- lines("file2.txt") ){ 
    do_stuff(l1, l2) 
}
```

This again, used to work fine with `2.8` but causes a "too many open files" 
exception to get thrown in `2.9`. This is understandable -- the second `lines` 
in the comprehension ends up opening (and not closing) a file for each line 
in the first.

In my case, I know that the `"file1.txt"` is big and I don't want to suck it into
memory, but the second file is small, so I can write a different `linesEager` 
like so:

```
def linesEager(filename: String): Iterator[String] = 
    val buf = scala.io.Source.fromFile(new File(filename))
    val zs  = buf.getLines().toList.toIterator
    buf.close()
    zs
```

and then turn my for-comprehension into:

```
for (l1 <- lines("file1.txt"); l2 <- linesEager("file2.txt")){ 
    do_stuff(l1, l2) 
}
```

This works, but is clearly ugly. Can someone suggest a uniform & clean 
way of achieving the above. Seems like you need a way for the iterator
returned by `lines` to `close` the file when it reaches the end, and 
this must have been happening in `2.8` which is why it worked there?

Thanks!

BTW -- here is a minimal version of the full program that shows the issue:

```
import java.io.PrintWriter
import java.io.File

object Fail { 

  def lines(filename: String) : Iterator[String] = { 
    val f = new File(filename)
    scala.io.Source.fromFile(f).getLines()
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]) = { 
    val smallFile = args(0)
    val bigFile   = args(1)

    println("helloworld")

    for ( w1 <- lines(bigFile)
        ; w2 <- lines(smallFile)
        ) 
    {
      if (w2 == w1){
        val msg = "%s=%s\n".format(w1, w2)
        println("found" + msg)
      }
    }

    println("goodbye")
  }

}
```

On `2.9.0` I compile with `scalac WordsFail.scala` and then I get this:

```
rjhala@goto:$ scalac WordsFail.scala 
rjhala@goto:$ scala Fail passwd words
helloworld
java.io.FileNotFoundException: passwd (Too many open files)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:91)
    at scala.io.Source$.fromFile(Source.scala:76)
    at Fail$.lines(WordsFail.scala:8)
    at Fail$$anonfun$main$1.apply(WordsFail.scala:18)
    at Fail$$anonfun$main$1.apply(WordsFail.scala:17)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:652)
    at scala.io.BufferedSource$BufferedLineIterator.foreach(BufferedSource.scala:30)
    at Fail$.main(WordsFail.scala:17)
    at Fail.main(WordsFail.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:78)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:24)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:88)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:78)
    at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:33)
    at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:40)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:56)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:80)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:89)
    at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Comment: Code one works for me in the REPL (Scala 2.9).

Comment: It wasn't the `;` unfortunately.

Comment: @userunknown It works but it does not scale. (Imagine large files / many lines.)

Comment: You are mistaken, `2.8` did not close anything either, as can easily be verified running `lsof` on a sample program (or more laboriously by looking at the source code). If you have problems with `2.9` that you did not with `2.8`, they must originate elsewhere.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[scala-arm](https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm) provides a great mechanism for automagically closing resources when you're done with them.

```
import resource._
import scala.io.Source

for (file1 <- managed(Source.fromFile("file1.txt"));
     l1 <- file1.getLines();
     file2 <- managed(Source.fromFile("file2.txt"));
     l2 <- file2.getLines()) {
  do_stuff(l1, l2)
}
```

But unless you're counting on the contents of `file2.txt` to change while you're looping through `file1.txt`, it would be best to read that into a `List` before you loop. There's no need to convert it into an `Iterator`.

Comment: Doesn't converting it into a list end up holding the whole file in memory? I was hoping to avoid that...

Comment: But `file2.txt` is small, so that should be acceptable. Plus, that's what your `linesEager` does (`.toList`), except that you're creating it in memory and throwing it away for every line in `file1.txt`.

Comment: Hi Dave, yes you are right. I was under the misapprehension that the different actions in the for-comprehension had to have the same type, and so the extraneous `toList.toIterator` when just `toList` would suffice...Thanks!

Comment: @RanjitJhala - Only when you yield a value form the for-comprehension, then the types need to be compatible. Not necessarily the same, but compatible.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should take a look at scala-arm (https://github.com/jsuereth/scala-arm) and let the closing of the files (file input streams) happen automatically in the background.